# How to convert array object in snowflake

Tags: javascript, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowsql

I would like to convert the below array of objects into another form (varname is ignored as its not required, key and value is used to generate the output form). Any leads would be appreciated

**Input array:**
[
{
"key": "string_U6",
"value": "grandwagoneer",
"varname": "pagenameplate"
},
{
"key": "string_U13",
"value": "2021",
"varname": "year"
}
]

**Output**

[
{
"string_U6": "grandwagoneer"
},
{
"string_U13": "2021"
}
]

Comment: Could you provide a code you are using to convert it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) as below:

```js
var input = [ { "key": "string_U6", "value": "grandwagoneer", "varname": "pagenameplate" }, { "key": "string_U13", "value": "2021", "varname": "year" } ];

var output = input.map(function(entry){
    let obj = {}; 
    obj[entry.key] = entry.value;
    return obj;
});

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 2):

As the question asked how to convert array object in **snowflake**, I wanted to share Snowflake way to do it:

```
-- SQL to create a sample table with data

create table sample_table (v variant ) 
as select parse_json(' [ { "key": "string_U6", "value": "grandwagoneer", "varname": "pagenameplate" },
{ "key": "string_U13", "value": "2021", "varname": "year" } ]');
    
-- query to parse the variant and create the array:

select ARRAY_AGG( OBJECT_CONSTRUCT(i.value:key::varchar, i.value:value::varchar) )  
from sample_table,
lateral flatten ( sample_table.v ) i;
```

It will produce exact output you want.